# Drawing grid next to text body

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]
I am writing a test for my students and I want to draw grid under every question for students to write solutions. Currently it looks like the above. Ideally, I also would like to have grid next to the answer choices as well as under the answer choices. (So the empty space on the right to the answer-choice column would be filled with grid)

How can I fill the blank space with grid?

Following is my MWE code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,answers]{exam}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength\columnsep{40pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

\newcommand{\solgrid}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,gray!30,very thin] (-10,0) grid (-3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{}

\begin{document}
\section*{Exam: 2024-03-18}
\markright{Exam: 2024-03-18}
\begin{multicols*}{2}


\begin{questions}

\question What number is 9 times smaller than $2\frac{1}{9}$  ? 

\begin{choices}
\choice $\frac{1}{2}$
\choice $\frac{1}{4}$
\choice $\frac{1}{9}$
\choice $\frac{1}{36}$
\choice $\frac{2}{9}$
\end{choices}
\solgrid

\end{questions}
\end{multicols*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: We currently don't know, how you made your question and the answers. So it is hard to guess, how to change the unknown code. I would recommend to show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), so we can reproduce you image and also test our ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am just starting to learn latex and I am all confused.  I edited my post to include what I hope suffices for a MWE. Again, thank you for the recommendation and help!

Comment: @NomiBaa, I think a line per choice suffices, is cleaner and easier to obtain. // E.g. with Tikz you could use the remember approach, but always need to know how many question there are and make sure, their vertical dimensions do not change. It will be easy to look ugly and hard to do it right. // You could also try the minipage environment with your \solgrid, with similar fundamental problems. // And there comes the pagebreak ... perhaps.

Comment: @MS-SPO, thanks for suggestion. I am a noob when it comes to latex. Can you elaborate how a line per choice results in a "cleaner and easier to obtain" solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: @NomiBaa, sorry, from a graphical design point of view I don't think your idea adds much value. If you want to mimick notebooks with grid, you'd ask for a grid background for every page. // Wrt to Latex I suggest getting a book for introduction, or here online: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX // Wrt the code you posted it probably will compile, but requires stuff not needed. I recommend improving it by applying https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . // The grid solutions from the manual https://ctan.org/pkg/exam don't make you happy (ch. 7), or the answer lines?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Personally, to do this type of MCQ I use the `tasks`  [tasks manual](https://texlive.mycozy.space/macros/latex/contrib/tasks/tasks-manual.pdf) environment which allows the choices to be displayed on a single line. Since students are entitled to a draft, this saves paper.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}
\newcommand{\solgrid}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, very thin]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gridx}{8.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gridy}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gridinset}{3}
\clip let \p1=(pic cs:startgrid) in ({\gridinset cm-\pgflinewidth},\y1) -- (\gridx cm+1cm,\y1) -- +(0,-\gridy cm-1cm) -| (0,{0.3cm+\pgflinewidth}) -|cycle;
\draw[step=0.5cm, gray, yshift=-0.2cm] let \p1=(pic cs:startgrid) in (0,{int(\y1*1pt/1cm)*1cm}) grid +(\gridx cm, -\gridy cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{\tikzmark{startgrid}}
\begin{document}
\section*{Exam: 2024-03-18}
\begin{questions}
\question What number is 9 times smaller than $2\frac{1}{9}$?
\begin{choices}
\choice $\frac{1}{2}$
\choice $\frac{1}{4}$
\choice $\frac{1}{9}$
\choice $\frac{1}{36}$
\choice $\frac{2}{9}$
\end{choices}
\solgrid
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: Question with choices under and a partial grid]

*Edit:* Now working also with multiple questions per page. It is not easy to make an automatic grid in the `exam` - it is missing styles for almost everything. I use a hack where `tikzmark`s are named with a counter. Using `grid` is problematic, as it needs integer values to look right and the `choices` start at different positions. -so drawing lines in a loop instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}
\newcounter{myn}
\newcommand{\solgrid}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, very thin, gray]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gridn}{17}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gridm}{12}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gridinset}{7}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\gridn}
\draw let \p1=(pic cs:startgrid\themyn) in ({0.5*\i},{\y1-(0.5*\gridm cm+0.3cm}) -- ({0.5*\i},{\i>=\gridinset?\y1-0.3cm:\y1-int((\y1-0.3cm)/0.5cm)*0.5cm-0.3cm});
\foreach \j in {0,...,\gridm}
\draw let \p1=(pic cs:startgrid\themyn) in ({\y1-0.3cm-0.5*\gridm cm+0.5*\j cm>0.5cm?0.5*\gridinset cm:0cm},{\y1-0.3cm-0.5*\gridm cm+0.5*\j cm}) -- ({0.5*\gridn cm},{\y1-0.3cm-0.5*\gridm cm+0.5*\j cm});
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{\stepcounter{myn}\tikzmark{startgrid\themyn}}
\begin{document}
\section*{Exam: 2024-03-18}
\begin{questions}
\question What number is 9 times smaller than $2\frac{1}{9}$?
\begin{choices}
\choice $\frac{1}{2}$
\choice $\frac{1}{4}$
\choice $\frac{1}{9}$
\choice $\frac{1}{36}$
\choice $\frac{2}{9}$
\end{choices}
\solgrid
\vspace{3cm}
\question What color is better than $2\frac{1}{9}$?
\begin{choices}
\choice red
\choice green
\end{choices}
\solgrid
\vspace{5cm}
\question What homeomorphisms is equivalent to $2\frac{1}{9}$?
\begin{choices}
\choice both
\choice green
\choice abricot
\choice hot
\choice yes
\choice true
\choice D.
\end{choices}
\solgrid
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: Multiple choice questions with a grid to the side]